# Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in

Tags: functions

we are receiving this error:

Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in /home/goose/public_html/wp-content/themes/goose/partials/contact.php on line 32
Please enter a valid email address

http://thegoosedarien.com - using the contact form, we receive this error message when submitting.

No idea how to resolve this. What is missing from the code?

```
<?php 

$asset_path = get_bloginfo('template_url');

?>

<div class="left">

<span class="main-title">
    <?php _e( 'Contact Us', 'goose' ); ?>
</span>

<?php 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { 

        $flag = 1; 

        echo '<div class="notice">';

        if($_POST['submission_name'] == '') { 
            $flag = 0; 
            echo "Please enter your name<br />";
        } else if(!preg_match('/[a-zA-Z_x7f-xff][a-zA-Z0-9_x7f-xff]*/', 
$_POST['submission_name'])) { 
            $flag=0; 
            echo "Please enter a valid name<br />"; 
        } 

        if($_POST['submission_email'] == '') { 
            $flag = 0; 
            echo "Please enter your email address<br />";
        } else if(!preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a- 
   z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_POST['submission_email'])) { 
            $flag=0; 
            echo "Please enter a valid email address<br />";
        } 

        if($_POST['submission_message'] == '') { 
            $flag = 0; 
            echo "Please enter a message<br />";
        }

        if (empty($_POST)) { 

            echo "Sorry, your submission is invalid - please try again!"; 
            exit; 

        } else { 

            if($flag == 1) { 
                wp_mail(get_option("admin_email"), 
trim($_POST[submission_name])." sent you a message from " . 
get_option("blogname"), stripslashes(trim($_POST[submission_message])),"From: ".trim($_POST[submission_name])." <".trim($_POST[submission_email]).">\r\nReply-To:".trim($_POST[submission_email]));
                echo "Submission successfully sent!<br />";
            }

        }

        echo '</div>';

    }

?>

<form method="post" parsley-validate parsley-show-errors="false" 
id="contact-form">
    <div class="line">
        <label for="name"><?php _e( 'Your Name', 'goose' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="submission_name" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <label for="email"><?php _e( 'Your Email', 'goose' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="submission_email" required="required" parsley-type="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <label for="msg"><?php _e( 'Message', 'goose' ); ?></label>
        <textarea id="msg" cols="10" rows="10" name="submission_message" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>  
    <button>
        <span><?php _e( 'Submit', 'goose' ); ?></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to avoid using `preg_match()`, because I get the pattern right very rarely. Perhaps you could try using some other functions to do the validating. For example PHP's [ctype_alnum()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) for the name field and WP's [is_email()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_email) for the email field. Like so,

```
if ( $_POST['submission_name'] == '' ) { 
  $flag = 0; 
  echo "Please enter your name<br />";
} else if ( ! ctype_alnum( $_POST['submission_name'] ) ) { // ctype_alnum returns TRUE if every character in text is either a letter or a digit, FALSE otherwise. 
  $flag = 0; 
  echo "Please enter a valid name<br />"; 
} 

if ( $_POST['submission_email'] == '' ) {
  $flag = 0; 
  echo "Please enter your email address<br />";
} else if ( ! is_email( $_POST['submission_email'] ) ) {
  $flag = 0; 
  echo "Please enter a valid email address<br />";
}
```

Also, if you want to make the `wp_mail()` function a little bit more readable, you could do something like this,

```
$name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['submission_name'] );
$email = sanitize_email( $_POST['submission_email'] );
$subject = sprintf( 
  '%s sent you a message from %s',
  $name,
  get_option("blogname")
);
$message = sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['submission_message'] );
$from = sprintf(
  "From: %s <%s>\r\n",
  $name,
  $email,
);
$reply_to .= sprintf(
  "Reply-To: %s",
  $email,
);
$headers = $from . $reply_to;
wp_mail(
  get_option("admin_email"),
  $subject,
  $message,
  $headers,
);
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nt9n6r

After implimenting the changes for the top recommendation, these errors occurred. 

What would be replaced with the wp_mail suggestion, beginning where?

Comment: About the errors, you're just missing some backtics on the code you posted. E.g this `$_POST[submission_name]` should be `$_POST['submission_name']`.

Comment: @LouisProcaccini Replace the the `wp_mail` function inside `if($flag == 1)` statement with the suggestion I posted. So the first three lines inside the `if`, but leave the success message line starting with `echo`.

Comment: Perfect. No errors.

Let me try to replace the wp_mail function now.

Comment: It's just a matter of taste and its not strictly necessary.

Comment: Now that the form submits without error, the captcha does not work or even appear for that contact form plugin

 http://prntscr.com/nt9xoy (settings)
http://prntscr.com/nt9xuk (captcha doesnt appear)

Comment: @LouisProcaccini The contact form fields on your partial file are hard coded, so probably none of those settings will have any effect on the contact form.

Comment: Can you recommend a hardcoded captcha or anti spam solution to implement?

Comment: @LouisProcaccini This comments section isn't the best place to propose solutions for captcha / antispam. Please ask it as a separate question so that others may provide their insights too.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but the answer might help someone else.

When using regular expressions, [you can use different delimiters for the expression](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character. Leading whitespace before a valid delimiter is silently ignored.

Usually, we use `/` to delimit it as in `/(\w)+/g`. But other characters like `^` are also allowed.

As we can see in your code, the first preg_match call uses `/`'s as delimiters: `/[a-zA-Z_x7f-xff][a-zA-Z0-9_x7f-xff]*/`, but the second preg_match call has no delimiter at all: `^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$`.

So, PHP is looking at the first character in the expression (`^`) and thinking it is a delimiter. When it doesn't find `^` at the end of the expression, it throws the warning `No ending delimiter '^' found`.

To fix it, all you need to do is add delimiters to your regex:

```
preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $_POST['submission_email'])
```

And that should be enough.